# apple magic keyboard not working trough bluetooth and fn button not working with cable

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I have a self built desktop pc (not apple) with ubuntu on it. I just bought a new apple magic keyboard, because I have a macbook air and I hate getting used to "the other" keyboard every time I switch, besides I like the feel of it.

I have 2 problems: 
- pressing keys doesn't do anything when connected trough bluetooth
- when connected trough the usb cable almost all keys work, except the FN key

I'm able to pair the keyboard, but after it "connects" it won't work (pressing keys won't do anything). 
I ran bluetoothctl from the terminal, paired, trusted, connected.
Most pages I follow trough google tell me to run "hidd", But it says command not found and I installed all the bluez-xxx packages.

Whenever I connect it trough the usb cable it works, but then the FN button won't work. Even when running XEV or "SHOWKEY -k", it will register all other buttons, but when pressing the FN key it doesn't even register the keypress. I feel like I tried everything, from upgrading the kernel (4.7 now), to connecting/disconnecting the keyboard that I had before. 
Most pages tell me to echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode, but hid_apple doesn't even exist. It looks like it's using hid_generic.
When I modprobe hid_apple it will exist but then putting 1 or 2 into fnmode won't do anything.

I also tried running dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration and choosing between several apple keyboards, but that doesn't make the FN button work either.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
No LSB modules are available.
Linux version 4.7.0-040700rc7-generic (kernel@gloin) (gcc version     5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1) ) #201607110032 SMP Mon Jul 11 04:34:25 UTC 2016
x86_64
```

and here's syslog output when re-connecting the keyboard trough the usb lightning cable:

```
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.524349] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.654196] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=0267
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.654201] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.654203] usb 3-1: Product: Magic Keyboard
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.654205] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.654207] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: F0T552400NGH1FKA6
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.661769] hid-generic 0003:05AC:0267.0007: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.663260] input: Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:05AC:0267.0008/input/input26
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.716847] hid-generic 0003:05AC:0267.0008: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
Jul 16 20:06:45  kernel: [ 2536.718220] hid-generic 0003:05AC:0267.0009: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
Jul 16 20:06:45  mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Jul 16 20:06:45  mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jul 16 20:06:49  colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul 16 20:06:49  gnome-session[1338]: (gnome-software:1657): Gs-WARNING **: failed to get updates: no results to show
```

I'm at a loss here on what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.